# Merge 2 edges that have the same head and tail In DOT

Tags: dot

I am using DOT to generate node relationships automatically from some technical specifications.
The problem I am facing is that, in some cases I have identical multiple transitions and DOT draws all of them. This seems like a feature more than a bug in DOT, but I need only 1 unique edge from node A to B and not multiple ones.

```
digraph "Main" {
A -> B
A -> B
}
```

DOT draws 2 edges for those 2 transitions and I only need to draw it once.
One approach is to do a parser of those specifications and ignore multiple identical transitions to be written in a doc file, but I assume that can be easily fixed with a edge attribute. I read the documentation and found nothing about such attributes.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edge concentration may help

```
digraph "Main" { concentrate=true
    A -> B
    A -> B
}
```

[image]

Be aware that concentration fails on edges with labels even if the labels are identical.

```
digraph "Main" { concentrate=true
    A -> B [label=a]
    A -> B [label=a]
}
```

[image]